# az cli 2.0 .... az webapp create runtime php|7.1 error

Tags: php, azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I am doing the following tutorial instructions. I using the CLI 2.0 that is integrated in the azure portal. Not the version on my laptop.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-php

```
az webapp create --resource-group xxxx-DevGroup --plan xxxxServicePlan --name hello --runtime "php|7.1" --deployment-local-git
```

and at the instruction to create the webapp i am getting this error:

```
'7.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

The runtimes 7.0 and 7.1 are supported. I also tried these variations without success.

```
php|7.1. I also tried php|7.0,  "php|7.1" and "php|7.0"
```

Any pointers to fix this issue would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log, it seems that you use a older version. You could use `az -v` to check version.

I test it on 2.0.7 and [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-php#launch-azure-cloud-shell), they all work for me.

[image]

I suggest you could upgrade your azure cli version or execute the command on [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-php#launch-azure-cloud-shell).

Comment: I am executing in the azure cloud shell. that is my problem. I am using chrome.should I use Edge?

Comment: Requesting a Cloud Shell.Succeeded.
Connecting terminal...

Welcome to Azure Cloud Shell

Type "az" to use Azure CLI 2.0
Type "help" to learn about Cloud Shell

kevin@Azure:~$ az -v
azure-cli (2.0.21)

Comment: ok, I re-tried the exactly same command as yesterday and this time it worked. weird!! anyway thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PowerShell, you need to do this:

az --% webapp create

The problem is az is escaping your string's bar "node|6.9", the --% disables it.

Comment: Where is this instruction on --% are documented in Azure Doc? I am trying to find the place where it mentioned this workaround. Can you please kindly paste the link?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never found documentation on it, but I know it works when my error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, the | will be seen als a command. Use single quotes to escape your string.

```
--runtime '"php|7.1"'
```